# Lemma 1.3.11 of Categories & Sheaves. Having trouble proving $F_0$ is unique up to unique isomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, proof-explanation

**Lemma 1.3.11.**  *Consider a functor $F: \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C'}$ and a full subcategory $\mathcal{C}_0'$ of $\mathcal{C}'$ such that for each $X \in \mathcal{C}$, there exists $Y \in \mathcal{C}_0'$ and an isomorphism $F(X) \simeq Y$.  Denote by $\iota'$ the embedding $\mathcal{C}_0' \to \mathcal{C}'$.  Then there exists a functor $F_0 : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}_0'$ and an isomorphism of functors $\theta_0: F \xrightarrow{\sim} \iota' \circ F_0$.  **Moreover, $F_0$ is unique up to unique isomorphism.  More precisely, given another isomorphism $\theta_1 : F \xrightarrow{\sim}\iota' \circ F_1$, there exists a unique isomorphism of functors $\theta : F_1 \xrightarrow{\sim}F_0$ such that $\theta_0 = (\iota'\circ\theta)\circ \theta_1$.***

Firstly, I'm not sure what they mean: do they mean $F_1$ has all the defining properties above that $F_0$ does?

I've proved everything up to the bolded part and not sure how to prove that.

Would this diagram be of any use in the proof?:
[image]

For example, what if we stuck two of these diagrams together "glued" at the $F$'s line, $F_1$'s on the topmost line.

Thanks.

Comment: I prefer a diagramatic / visual proof, thanks.  I'm working on one now.  So no rush on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Firstly, I'm not sure what they mean: do they mean $F_1$ has all the defining properties above that $F_0$ does?

Here is what we know $F_0$ satisfies: there exists a $\theta : F \overset{\sim}{\to} \iota' \circ F_0$.

Note that since composition by functors preserves isomorphisms of functors, this property is already invariant on isomorphism classes of functors.

The functors $F_1$ satisfying this property are unique up to isomorphism if knowing there exists $\theta_1 : F \overset{\sim}{\to} \iota' F_1$ implies there exists an $\eta : F_1 \overset{\sim}{\to} F_0$ down in $\mathcal{C}'_0$ such that the triangle

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
F @>\theta_0>> \iota' F_0 \\
  @| @A \iota' \circ \eta AA\\
F @>\theta_1>> F_1
\end{CD}$$

commutes.

They're unique up to unique isomorphism if this isomorphism $\eta : F' \simeq F_0$ is unique (while still satisfying the triangle above).

To see this, construct the isomorphism in $\mathcal{C}'$. Pointwise, it's given by inverting $\theta_0$ and then composing by $\theta_1$. Because $\iota'$ is full and faithful, you can lift this constructed isomorphism down to $\mathcal{C}_0'$. And it's unique because it was constructed uniquely from the very data you had to satisfy.

Comment: In your diagram, don't you mean $\iota' F_1$ in the lower right corner?

Comment: Please respond to the comment section, thx

Answer (score 2):

*Firstly, I'm not sure what they mean: do they mean $F_1$ has all the defining properties above that $F_0$ does?*

No, $F_1$ is an arbitrary functor $C\to C_0'$, such that there exists an isomorphism $\theta_1\colon F\to\iota'\circ F_1$.

*I've proved everything up to the bolded part and not sure how to prove that.*

Let $F_1$ be such a functor. Then the natural transformation $\theta_{1,0}=\theta_0\circ\theta_1^{-1}\colon\iota'\circ F_1\to\iota'\circ F_0$ is an isomorphism. Define the natural transformation $\theta\colon F_1\to F_0$ in the following way: $\theta(X)=\theta_{1,0}(X)$ for every $X\in C$. Note, that $\theta$ is an isomorphism because $C_0'$ is a full subcategory. Also $\theta_0=\theta_{1,0}\circ\theta_1=(\iota'\circ\theta)\circ\theta_1$.

If $\theta'\colon F_1\to F_0$ is an another isomorphism with such property, then it is easy to see that $\iota'\circ\theta=\iota'\circ\theta'$, hence $\theta=\theta'$.

[image]

It may be easier to think about $\theta$ as the "*corestriction*" $\theta=\theta_{1,0}|^{C'_0}$.

*Would this diagram be of any use in the proof?*

This diagram shows that $F_0$ is a functor, so it is not useful in the proof of the statement in bold. I added the diagram which may appear helpful in visual understanding of this fact, but it is not a proof, of course.

Comment: I disagree with you.  Just because a computer can't easily parse an image does not mean it's not a proof.  We  just differ in our definitions of what a proof is.  I will try to make a full visual proof from your post.

Comment: @EnjoysMath Indeed, it depends on the definition of the proof. I usually prefer to draw diagrams and to write words near them, so proof for me is an oredered pair (words,diagrams). But I don't see anything bad in your approach. Good luck!